# built in __dict__ is returning names of attributes with class names as prefix

Tags: python, dictionary, instance-variables, python-internals

```
class Enrollment(object):

    def __init__(self,enrollmentId=None, enrollmentReference=None):
        self.enrollmentId = enrollmentId
        self.enrollmentReference = enrollmentReference

    @property
    def enrollmentId(self):
        return self.__enrollmentId

    @enrollmentId.setter
    def enrollmentId(self, enrollmentId):
        self.__enrollmentId = enrollmentId

    @property
    def enrollmentReference(self):
        return self.__enrollmentReference

    @enrollmentReference.setter
    def enrollmentReference(self, enrollmentReference):
        self.__enrollmentReference = enrollmentReference
```

If i now try to print the attributes of the above class:

```
print(Enrollment().__dict__)
```

It prints the attributes prefixed with class name as below:

```
{'_Enrollment__enrollmentId': None, '_Enrollment__enrollmentReference': None}
```

Note: If I remove object as the super class, all works well and it prints the attributes correctly as below:

```
{'enrollmentId': None, 'enrollmentReference': None}
```

I have been been wrapping my head around this for 2 days now with no luck. 
Not able to understand why the class name is prefixed to attributes. I need to serialize the `Enrollment` object to JSON.

Comment: I don't this is a duplicate because it asks "what causes this effect?"

Comment: I am puzzled why it does not happen with old style class and how can i get around with it in new style classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a class definition, Python transforms `__x` into `_classname__x`.  This is called [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Python).  Its purpose is to support class local references so that subclasses don't unintentionally break the internal logic of the parent class.

Comment: Thanks for compact/ordered dicts.

Comment: @Raymond - Thanks for the short and precise reply. I am puzzled why it does not happen with old style class and how can i get around with it in new style classes.I need a dictionary of attributes to pass on to json.dumps serializer

Comment: The single underscore worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

### Cause

This is due to Python's [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) of class attribute names that start with `__` and are suffixed with at most a single `_`. This suggests a stricter privacy for these attributes.

Note: This is still a heuristic and shouldn't be counted on for access prevention.

From the docs:

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

```
class A:
    def __foo_(self): pass

print(vars(A))
```

outputs

```
{'__module__': '__main__', '_A__foo_': <function A.__foo_ at 0x1118c2488>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

Notice that `__foo_` has been mangled into `_A__foo_`.

### Uses

Why might this be useful? Well the example from the docs is pretty compelling:

> Name mangling is helpful for letting subclasses override methods without breaking intraclass method calls. For example:

```
class Mapping:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.items_list = []
        self.__update(iterable)

    def update(self, iterable):
        for item in iterable:
            self.items_list.append(item)

    __update = update   # private copy of original update() method

class MappingSubclass(Mapping):

    def update(self, keys, values):
        # provides new signature for update()
        # but does not break __init__()
        for item in zip(keys, values):
            self.items_list.append(item)
```

### tldr

Read [the docs on name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).